# WCF REST interface and caching

Tags: wcf, caching

I have a WCF web service that implements a RESTful interface. We're using the InstanceContextMode of PerCall, and are looking for options to use for caching objects for reuse on subsequent calls.

We're looking to override/extend the WCF Context logic in order to create/maintain/clean up objects to be shared among implementation methods of a PerCall service interface.

I'd also like to see a diagram of the objects created/used during a call to a WCF interface. I have a very nice one for ASP.Net event calls, but I haven't found anything for WCF. I'm not sure which classes to override or interfaces to implement to interject my own logic into the WCF call hierarchy for persisting objects between calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for events happening, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx) is a must read - there are very nice diagrams there as well.

Objects created very much depend on your configuration. With WCF REST, I imagine it must be small.

If I were you, I would not go down the route of caching and solving a problem that does not exists - or at least I assume so from your question. `PerCall` is the only scalable setting. Also I imagine a REST service would be designed as stateless anyway.

Comment: We need to cache some objects that potentially take a long time to create because of their data sources. Being able to reuse them in each of the individual contexts would save a lot of processing time. And yes, were going with PerCall since none of the other options fit our needs.

Comment: So this is purely a caching question, is it not? I imagine you are using IIS hence ` System.Runtime.Caching.Cache`??

Comment: I'll edit the question. I'm more interested in overriding the WCF Context logic to create and maintain objects needed in a PerCall interface methods.

Comment: marked as an answer because that document was very helpful. Thanks.